# antlr4 python3 grammar on github

Tags: python-3.x, antlr, antlr4

I'm using the grammar posted here:
https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/python3

It sometime returns partial tokens or multiple tokens before emitting the correct token. I'm using the TestRig tool to print the following output.

Is this expected behavior ? Thank you.

```
@0,0:4='#3.31',<92>,channel=2,1:0]
****[@1,6:7='de',<34>,2:0]
[@2,6:8='def',<1>,2:0]****
[@3,10:23='reverse_string',<35>,2:4]
[@4,24:24='(',<47>,2:18]
[@5,25:30='answer',<35>,2:19]
[@6,31:31=')',<48>,2:25]
[@7,32:32=':',<50>,2:26]
****[@8,38:39='an',<34>,3:4]
[@9,38:42='answe',<94>,3:4]
[@10,38:43='answer',<35>,3:4]****
[@11,45:45='=',<53>,3:11]
[@12,47:51='input',<35>,3:13]
[@13,52:52='(',<47>,3:18]
[@14,53:82=''Enter a three-letter string:'',<36>,3:19]
[@15,83:83=')',<48>,3:49]
*[@16,89:90='re',<34>,4:4]
[@17,89:94='return',<2>,4:4]*
[@18,96:101='answer',<35>,4:11]
....

[@25,114:118='#3.32',<92>,channel=2,6:4]
*[@26,124:125='de',<34>,7:4]
[@27,124:126='def',<1>,7:4]*
...

**[@42,183:184='re',<34>,9:12]
[@43,183:195='return rate *',<94>,9:12]
[@44,183:188='return',<2>,9:12]
[@45,190:193='rate',<35>,9:19]
[@46,195:195='*',<46>,9:24]**
```

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not expected behaviour.

During the creation of tokens, I assigned the wrong start and stop indices of custom created tokens (see `private CommonToken commonToken(int type, String text)` in `Python3.g4`).

These `re` and `ret` nodes were really `NEWLINE` and `INDENT` tokens. So only their inner text had misguided data, their token-types *are* the correct `NEWLINE` and `INDENT`.

Fixed in Pull Request: https://github.com/bkiers/python3-parser/pull/5 which will be merged shortly in `master`. And I've also proposed the change on the official ANTLR4 grammar repo: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/pull/155

Comment: Thank you. It works for most part but still there is a problem: It is returning a token of type -1 at the end:  Last statement in python source was: "return x"
@380,1250:1255='return',<2>,63:8]
[@381,1257:1257='x',<35>,63:15]
[@382,1257:1257='x',<34>,63:16]
[@383,1257:1257='x',<95>,63:16]
[@384,1257:1257='x',<95>,63:16]
[@385,1253:1257='urn x',<-1>,63:16]

Comment: @user4848830 note that -1 is just the EOF token. Could you checkout the master branch of https://github.com/bkiers/python3-parser and try? If it still shows `"urn"` in the EOF token, please create an issue again with the python input you used so that I can reproduce it.